# Consulta de datos a través del ultimo carácter de un input

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy queriendo tomar el ultimo carácter de cualquier texto que ingrese por input y al realizar la búsqueda me imprima los datos de la tabla que contiene ese ultimo carácter, teniendo en cuenta que solo deseo que lo asocie con la columna llamada placa de la base de datos.

Adjunto la consulta que realizo en la base de datos mysql, con esta consulta y la sentencia LIKE, me muestra tal cual lo quiero.

`SELECT p.placa, p.horario_cir, p.dia_res, a.restriccion   FROM horarios as p INNER JOIN dias_restric as a ON p.dia_res = a.dia   WHERE p.placa LIKE '1%';`

Recalco que esta consulta en la base de datos me hace extacamente lo que necesito, a excepción de que cuando quiero que busque el cero '0%', no me imprime nada.

Esta misma consulta al aplicarla en PHP y colocando el cero en el input me imprime todos los datos, ahora lo que yo busco es que tome el ultimo carácter del texto que ingreso en input, para este ejemplo serán las placas de un auto (PCA-1890), necesito que me imprima los datos que contengan solo el ultimo carácter que este dentro de la columna placa y lo del cero.

Pondre el codigo php para que se pueda entender lo que realizo.

```
<?php
    $search_keyword = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT p.placa, p.horario_cir, p.dia_res, a.restriccion  
    FROM horarios as p INNER JOIN dias_restric as a ON p.dia_res = a.dia  
    WHERE p.placa LIKE :keyword ';
    
    $query = $sql;
    $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $resultados = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
?>
```

Esto es lo que hace la consulta desde la base de datos
Y esto es solo el html de donde se toma el dato a buscar.

```
<form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
                        <div style='text-align:right;margin:20px 0px;'>

                            <!--<input type='text' name='search[keyword]' value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword' maxlength='25'>-->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <h3> Ingresa la placa de tu vehículo </h3>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busqueda..." name='search[keyword]' value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword' maxlength='25'>
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class='table-header' width='5%'>Nro de Placa.</th>
                                        <th class='table-header' width='25%'>Horario de Circulacion</th>
                                        <th class='table-header' width='40%'>Dia de Restricción</th>
                                        <th class='table-header' width='10%'>Horario de No Circulación</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id='table-body'>
                                    <?php
                                    if (!empty($resultados)) {
                                        foreach ($resultados as $row) {
                                    ?>
                                            <tr class='table-row'>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['placa']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['horario_cir']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['dia_res']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['restriccion']; ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Como mencione, solo necesito que al ingresar la placa en el input, busque los datos en las tablas con el ultimo carácter de la placa ingresada, tomando como referencia solo la columna placa de la base de datos. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Aparte de exponer lo que quieres hacer, debes demostrar que lo has intentado, sino nos estas asignando una tarea, y aquí no hacemos tareas. Orientación: Para extraer el último carácter de un string puedes usar `mb_substr($string, -1);`. Ahora intenta la consulta y si no te sale edita la pregunta agregando el código que hayas intentado y el error que tienes para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [**`substr()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) para obtener el último carácter de la cadena. Por otra parte, todo el bloque de consulta debería estar dentro del `if`, pues como lo tienes actualmente la consulta se ejecutaría si no hay término de búsqueda en el POST, lo cual no tendría sentido.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
        $lastChar=substr($search_keyword, -1);
        $sql = "SELECT p.placa, p.horario_cir, p.dia_res, a.restriccion  
        FROM horarios as p INNER JOIN dias_restric as a ON p.dia_res = a.dia  
        WHERE p.placa LIKE :keyword";
        $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
        $pdo_statement->bindValue(":keyword", "%$lastChar%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo_statement->execute();
        $resultados = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
    }
    #Falta decidir acción si no hay datos a buscar
    
?>
```